# package to import for mx:XML

Tags: apache-flex

I am creating an app with Flex 4 using Flash Builder. When I try to use `mx:XML` component, I get the error `Could not resolve <mx:XML> to a component implementation.` Can any one tell me which package to import to resolve this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `<fx:XML` (assuming that you are using the default namespaces generated by FB). Also it should stay in `<fx:Declarations>` area.

Answer (score 0):

the XML class is in the top level package, so it should be included in your project by default.

The problem is probably to do with the namespace/s that are in use (i.e. the xmlns attributes of your root MXML element)

Some information and possible solutions [here](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/could-not-resolve-mx-to-a-component-implementation) and [here](http://life.neophi.com/danielr/2007/01/could_not_resolve_to_a_compone.html)